# How do you enter a login passcode without a dualshock controller?

Tags: ps4, controllers

I haven't used my PS4 in quite some time. Now when I switch the PS4 on I'm taken to this screen.

I can't find my old PS4 controller so I had to buy a new one, but it won't connect to the console, even with a new PS4 lead.

I need help to get past this screen. I *do* know the passcode.

This is what the passcode screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: So my understanding is, you know the passcode, but since you don't have a controller that works, you can't type it in, and you need a way to get past this screen right?

Comment: Is your issue that you don't have a ps4 controller that is connected already? Can't you connect the controller to the ps4 using the usb cable that comes with it which will charge and connect your controller to the console - then you can just input the passcode using your new controller that's wired to the console.

Comment: Since OP did not respond to the two comments above asking for clarification, this question should be closed as "Needs details or clarity".

Comment: A USB keyboard might work?

Answer (score 1):

If your PS4 controller is legit, and you can be sure it is somewhat charged, try:

"If your PS4 controller won't connect, try a different USB cable, in case the original one has failed. You can also reset the PS4 controller by pressing the button on the back of the controller. If your controller still won't connect to your PS4, you might need to get support from Sony."

If not given that the symbols employed to enter the passcode, that you know, are only found on the controller, I think the only other plausible solution could be trying/buying another PS4 controller. Or if you are a gifted techie finding some way of hacking the input interface to allow the symbols to be entered using a wireless (or wired) keyboard that the PS4 recognises.

As an addendum to the above, if trying it in another USB port also fails then your console may have damaged or dirty USB connectors? Try cleaning them in that latter case. Don't give up! :)